# Jquery load not allowing a loaded form to submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

The first file loads the contents of the second file into a div called "pull_table".

The second file contains a form which submits fine when the second file is ran individually, however when the contents is pulled when loading the first file, the form is unable to submit.

file1.php

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pull_table").load("file2.php");
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="pull_table"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

file2.php

```
<?php 
$test_post="";

if (isset($_POST['test_post'])) {
    $test_post = $_POST['test_post'];
}

echo $test_post;

?>

<form action="" name="inputs" method="POST">
<input id="test_post" name="test_post" value="THIS FORM SUBMITTED!!" >
<input class="" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Original question made redundant this shows the most basic functionality.

Comment: You have ever post this question and I gave an answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226009/jquery-load-function-will-not-allow-form-to-submit

Comment: The code in this question was changed so the answer was not applicable to the new amended code?

Comment: Looks the same to me. What's different about it?

Comment: @AshleyColton then you should ask as comment in your original question. Better building on foundation or building from scratch?

Comment: ???? this question has removed code due it becoming confusing of what is actually trying to be achieved...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/file2.php" name="inputs" method="POST">
```

Looks like you are missing path in action attribute to file2.php

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: hi thanks tried this earlier but didnt seem to work, i left it blank so it runs at what page it is on.

Comment: @AshleyColton "didnt seem to work" - can you tell what happened? You got redirected to /file2.php or.. ?